# No sound from USB speakers under Ubuntu (working fine under Windows)

Tags: usb, speakers

I am a first time user of Ubuntu. I recently installed it as a dualboot with **Windows 7**. I have **Logitech USB** speakers which work fine in **Windows**. However, I can't get any audio to play in Ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an output from the Terminal:

```
home@ubuntu:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC887 Analog [ALC887 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 2):

Open system setting then go to sound and under the hardware tab you should find your speakers if you dont know which one to choose then just click test and keep trying you wont ddamage your system.

Comment: I tried all four options, including 'Digital Output (S/PDIF) USB Audio'. None of them worked. I clicked on Test Sound and didn't hear anything from my speakers. I just tried plugging them into the front USB port and they work fine there. Is there a way I can get them to work in the rear port? They work in Windows in the rear port.

Comment: Can you find out if your back usb port is version 1, 2 or 3 this might help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I believe it is USB 2.0.

Comment: It's working now. I have four USB ports in the back. I tried plugging in my speakers to different ones and it finally worked. It still doesn't work in the one I had it in originally. But it works in Windows and Ubuntu in the current port so I'm happy. Thanks so much for your help Mark. So far, I'm really liking Ubuntu!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out mate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set these as default, please refer to this question - [16.04 Headphones detected, but not switched on automatically after startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769593/16-04-headphones-detected-but-not-switched-on-automatically-after-startup)

Comment: Not a good practice to only share a link. Please include the essential part of the solution in your answer and give the link as reference and more detail.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. They can follow the link.

Comment: Duplicate questions should be reported (flagged) as duplicate so they will be closed.

Comment: I can't do that. Not enough reputation. If you'd like to, the above link is the question with the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Install Veromix. Start the application and select the device you want to use as the default device.