# Logitech S100 USB speakers output no sound on Ubuntu 15.04, USB 1.1

Tags: usb, sound, xubuntu, 15.04, kvm-switch

I am a first time user of Ubuntu. I recently installed it as a dualboot with Windows 7. I have Logitech S100 USB speakers which work fine in Windows. However, I can't get any audio to play in Ubuntu.

```
brandy ~ 270# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I know this seems similar to [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169675/need-help-with-usb-speakers), but this one is slightly different.

My speakers run through a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) with USB 1.1.  I know the speakers work over USB 1.1, because they work on windows.  I mention this because it was mentioned in the other posting (above).

I am working with Xubuntu 15.04, so I'm not running Unity.  Xfce or command line options would help.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I needed in `pavucontrol`.  It's not a USB thing, and it's still unclear why there is no **Sound**  option in the settings menu.